# Eslint error when root folder contains multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslintrc

When I created multiple projects use vue-cli in one folder, vscode showed following eslint error info:

```
Parsing error: No Babel config file detected for /Users/yuhongbo/Desktop/code-2022/micro-web/vue2/src/main.js. Either disable config file checking with requireConfigFile: false, or configure Babel so that it can find the config files.eslint
```

[image]

It works good when I opened these projects in vscode separately, I mean one project one window, but I want them work fine when they open in one root folder.

Comment: I have figured out, just add `{"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]}` to the `settings.json` file in the `.vscode` folder